# React display data from object TypeError: value map is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, object, google-cloud-firestore

Getting "TypeError: value is undefined" error when trying to render the data from the value object, when I console log value the object does show.

**CODE**

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  useDocumentData,
} from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import firebase from "../firebase";

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const Threads = () => {
  const { threadId } = useParams();
  const [value, loading, error] = useDocumentData(firestore.collection("threads").doc(threadId));
  console.log(value);
  return (
    <div>
      {value.map((thread, i) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{thread.title}</h1>
          <p>{thread.desc}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Threads;
```

**CONSOLE**

[image]

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: I think, it's because your value it's an object, not an array. You can't map an object. Or, you can try this `[value].map((thread, i) => { }`

Comment: With that change the error changed to this TypeError: thread is undefined

Comment: You can make sure the type of your value, is an array or an object. You can look at the result. If it not an array, then you cant map it. You can use `Array.isArray(value)` to check it

Comment: This returned false, is there any way I could get the data from this object to display it?

Answer (score 1):

The variable value is a object. Map function in JS is applicable only for arrays.
So try this.

```
        <div>
          <h1>{value.title}</h1>
          <p>{value.desc}</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: I get the error saying TypeError: value is undefined